How to read clickhouse bitmap with C# code
I am building a c# service which need to query Clickhouse, we're using ClickHouse.Client to access Clickhouse, while seems the library does not support to read roaring bitmap directly, is there any solution for this scenario? appreciate any suggestions.

Are you using https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/functions/bitmap-functions  or the eqv. agg state?
